# Bulk import 301 redirects in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-6, http-status-code-301

Is there a mechanism, or any additional tools that I can make use of to bulk import 301 redirect rules into an IIS6.0 web application? I want to be able to 301 redirect some old .htm pages to their new home on a CMS to ensure the current search index entries resolve OK and don't 404, but there are roughly ~50 pages. The only way I've found to achieve this is to create dummy .htm files and then right click on the file->File tab->Redirect to a URL radio button within the IIS MMC snapin, which is a little laborious over the number of pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little head scratching, I went for Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter at http://iirf.codeplex.com/. This allowed me to create a .htaccess-like file with the 50-odd redirects in it, and didn't require me to have dummy .htm files littered within the web application.

Comment: Do you have an example of your redirect file? I'm trying to get my head round how this module works.